# Adjust font size of Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webkit, webview, font-size

How do you adjust the font size of an Android `WebView`? The following appears to have no effect:

```
private void fontSizePlus() {
    fontSize = (fontSize < FONT_SIZE_MAX) ? fontSize + FONT_SIZE_INCREMENT : fontSize;
    this.changeFontSize(fontSize);
}

private void fontSizeMinus() {
    fontSize = (fontSize > FONT_SIZE_MIN) ? fontSize - FONT_SIZE_INCREMENT : fontSize;
    this.changeFontSize(fontSize);
}

private void changeFontSize(int value) {
    String js = "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '" + value + "%';";
    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + js +  " })()");  
}
```

Where the `WebView` and constants have been initialized as follows:

```
private final static int FONT_SIZE_DEFAULT = 100;
private final static int FONT_SIZE_MIN = 50;
private final static int FONT_SIZE_MAX = 150;
private final static int FONT_SIZE_INCREMENT = 5;
private int fontSize = FONT_SIZE_DEFAULT;

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.index);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.htm");
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

@rob's answer and comment pointed me in the right direction.

First make sure that all font sizes are relative to the default font size. If you use absolute values the following will not work on those elements.

Then:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    fontSize = mWebView.getSettings().getDefaultFontSize();
    ...
}

private void fontSizePlus() {
    fontSize++;
    this.changeFontSize(fontSize);
}

private void fontSizeMinus() {
    fontSize--;
    this.changeFontSize(fontSize);
}

private void changeFontSize(int value) {
    mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(value);
}
```

By changing the value of the default font size all relative font sizes are adjusted accordingly. This gives you much greater control than `WebSettings.setTextSize (WebSettings.TextSize t)`.

Comment: here my webview is adapter class how to use `fontSizePlus` and `fontSizeMinus` thank's

Comment: This did not work for me. But Brian Cooley's suggestion did: `settings.setTextZoom( (int)(settings.getTextZoom() * 0.85) );`

Answer (score 4):

I don't know that `webkitTextSizeAdjust` is supported in anything other than safari/mobile safari.

Try `WebSettings.setTextSize (WebSettings.TextSize t)`

rather than trying to do it with javascript.

Comment: That seems to be the problem, yes. Unfortunately WebSettings.TextSize has only 5 possible values, which I find too limiting. Is this the best that WebView offers for this problem?

Comment: Well, there is always plain old css.  That is, adjust the fontSize on the body element or the like.

Comment: +1 Your comment pointed me in the right direction. Will post the solution shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Brian Cooley helped me with this...try it...

```
increaseFontButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        WebSettings settings = myWebView.getSettings();
        settings.setTextZoom( (int)(settings.getTextZoom() * 1.1) );
    }
}
```