# Font resize doesn't work for a Webview in a fragment (FrameLayout)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-framelayout

I'm using this code to resize the font in my webview:

```
private void changeFontSize(int value) {
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(fontSize);
}

private void fontSizePlus() {
    if (fontSize<FONT_SIZE_MAX){
    fontSize++;
    Log.d(TAG,"Font size = "+fontSize);
    this.changeFontSize(fontSize);
    }
}

private void fontSizeMinus() {
    if (fontSize>FONT_SIZE_MIN){
    fontSize--;
    Log.d(TAG,"Font size = "+fontSize);
    this.changeFontSize(fontSize);
    }
}
```

This code works very well when i'm using it for a webview in an Activity. But when i'm using it for a webview in a FrameLayout, it doesn't work anymore. Also when I press font_size_up and font_size_down buttons, no log message in the log!

This is the web content:
    String yourHtml = HTML CODE
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, yourHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
NB:Sorry I didn't know how to post my HTML code so it will appear and not treated as html code here in the browser

Comment: Do you really need a WebView?..

Comment: Yes for sure because I want to show HTML/CSS data in the details page. Exactly, I have a listview in the left side and a details page on the right side. Before using this fragments layout(I had a simple Activity to Activity layout), my code was working very well. But when I implemented this layout, can't resize the font.

Comment: If you don't see any logs in logcat check your conditions first. They can be false `fontSize>FONT_SIZE_MIN` and `fontSize<FONT_SIZE_MAX`. Debug your code first, it can even be not an error of WebView.

Comment: I removed the "if" conditions to check the code, so when i press font_size_up button, the font resizes directly to max (Font must resizes step by step by incrementing the size) and also no log message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that you can resize font in the webview content. You could change the font size in the HTML content of the web page if you are reading the web page from a file, but not if you are reading the page from a URL.

Comment: I edited my question so you can see the HTML content and how I'm loading it

Comment: ah...ok. So the problem is that you want to change the font size dinamically on button click or what?

Comment: Yes I'm using a font_down and font_up buttons. My code was working very well before using Framelayout and fragment

Comment: No, I tried it now, but this method can't take "int" as parameter.So how can I use it?

Comment: try looking here for the answer..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188168/adjust-font-size-of-android-webview

Comment: Thank you very much, thats the solution!My bug was: I was using absolute values for the font size, now when i changed them to relative to the default font size, everything works very nice. Note that I must use 
    mWebView.getSettings().getDefaultFontSize();
in onActivitycreated method.